# pass value from gridview to stored procedure

Tags: c#

I had stored procedure which get data where Id=@id and the @id which pass to stored from gridview I tried to do that but I couldnot please any one help me

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
    using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        string Sql = "Select Logo From Model where Id=@Id";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
        com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Id", GridView1.SelectedDataKey));
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string Img2 = dr["Logo"].ToString();
            if (Img2 == System.DBNull.Value.ToString())
            {
                Img.Visible = false;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to do here. GridView1_RowDataBound will be invoked for every row present in the gridview - do you want to run the query for each row in gridview to retrieve the data? If yes then you can use `e.Row.DataItem` property to get underlying data (DataRowView if using data-table/view or object instance if using object data source). You can also use `e.Row.DataItemIndex` to look up into your data source to get the corresponding data row and get the id from there.